# Role-based authentification in android app using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, roles, user-roles

I am developing an android app and using firebase database. It contains authorization and few activities for different roles. If you are entering as "Installer" opens one activity and if as "Contact-Centre" - another, but now it's not important. So I need to check a role of entered pair of email and password.  So what I should to do?

Here is my database structure:

[image: database structure]

Sign in code:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Аутентификация прошла успешно",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RoleInstallerForm.class));
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Проверьте правильность введённых данных", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add some code if you have tried any and also elaborate your problem . . .

Comment: I havent code that can detalyse my problem, i tried default authroriztion using Firebase (samples from assiastant). Thats my first project with android studio, so all that i can is searchin in the net. What i want: get user's role from firebase database to open appropriate page. Atm i uses list of users (Auth point in firebase console) and it haven't  any ways to give roles to users. If i create custom database and fiil it with user's data, can i create a method that catch for pair of email and pass appropriate role (i've wrote a sample from c# and sql above) and use it further.

Comment: I need only direction (tries to work with database data like in c# and sql or use firestone's custom claims). Just i have no idea what is possible and atm the net doesnt gave me an answer.

Comment: Yes, when a new user is registered you have to update the role in database. And fetch it when you need it in app. I have no idea how your app structure is going to be or what are you going to do with that roles, so I cannot help much. If you can add more information, I can help. :-)

Comment: Structure for now: Auth page, 2 different pages for appropriate roles and mb page with settings. What i want atm: while auth, get user's role and based on it open the page and in some place show his name.

Comment: Okay so how are you going to assign the role to user? I mean are you going to allow the user themselves to choose their roles?

Comment: I found some vids, and as i understand it, firestore with his collections can help me, right? I can store information of user there and gets name, role and etc. and use it in app.

Comment: mmm maybe Firebase realtime database will be better for this purpose as you will have to check the role again and again. Yes just store the role in firebase database [you can use firestore if you want to] and whenever you want to verify anything just fetch role and add an `if-else` statement to divert your users.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answers, mb can u give me one more advice. My app will contain user's requests (app for internet-provider, non-commercial, it's theme of my diploma). Each request have status (open, in work (when user took it) , closed (user will do it manually and leave a comment) and name of the user that works with request. Is it realisable? As I understand, to do it I must use collection that contains info about user and works with uid, right?

Comment: About roles. On auth pages i placed the switch that allow user to change his role but for now idk how to realise it with firebase, i will abandon the firebase auth database and start to use custom database. At this moment im just searching info and ways to realise my project.

Comment: What im doing now: i have Auth database (beforehand sorry for cyrillic) - https://prnt.sc/sa2zrq and Cloud Firestore database with other info about user - https://prnt.sc/sa301k. So atm im trying to find how to get data from firestore for user that signed in.

Comment: For choosing role, I'll suggest to add 2 radio buttons and ask the user to choose their role. I would be happy to help you further. But as far as I know too subjective question aren't to be asked here. Let's solve your next question with some code if you get stuck.

Comment: At this moment my Firestore base is https://prnt.sc/sa4vn5. How i see it: i'm can get uid of the user that signed in (currUser = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); uid = user.getUid();) and then search in users collection document with same name and get role to open appropriate page. But idk where in code place it. In mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword or after this? And how to search in firestore with uid value? I cant find any sample. Mb u know some documentation or tutorial? I spent all day to find something but didnt found anything that i can embed in my app.

Comment: Again this is not a place for long discussion. Please Contact me on telegram or instagram `@dharmaraj_24`

Comment: Can u add me in contact list, @QuqAuq, I don't know why, but I can't send messages to people who I'm not in the list.

Comment: I texted you probably.. check once :-) at telegram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to this:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Àóòåíòèôèêàöèÿ ïðîøëà óñïåøíî",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                currentUserUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            }catch (Throwable throwable){
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }

            roleRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserUID).child("Role");
            roleRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    try {
                        String userRole = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                        //Add if-else here if you need any
                        //For example:
                        //I DONT UNDERSTAND RUSSIAN ROLE YOU TYPE
                        // JUST REPLACE THE ROLE NAMES
                        if(userRole.equals(leader)){
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, some-activity.class));
                        }else{
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, other-activity.class));
                        }
                    }catch (Throwable e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });   

         }
         else {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Ïðîâåðüòå ïðàâèëüíîñòü ââåä¸ííûõ äàííûõ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
     }
 });
```